# Best solution for text blur + all browser support - fallback ideas?

Tags: css, text, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, blur

I need your suggestions.

For a eBook webshop I need to show parts of the text and partial a "pseudo" blured text:
Here is my example link for different tests I did:
http://dokumente-online.com/test-blur.html

This should be used as a effect only,  so the text behind should have the structure of the real text (font size, chapters) but in fact it is only "lorem ipsum" or whatever. It should only tell the customer "there is more, it looks like this"

First idea was: a blurred image.
Con: It is always the same picture and it might be missleading if the text is formatted much different.

With CSS3 I can use this blur effect which works well on most modern browsers:

```
`color: rgba(94,94,94,0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(50,50,50, .7);`
```

Works on chrome, firefox, safari and opera so far.

But what can I do with the usual nerving **Internet Explorer?**
text-shadow is not supported, even on IE10 **RGBa()** is not supported.

At the moment I test with browsershot.org and it confuses me:
http://browsershots.org/http://dokumente-online.com/test-blur.html
It looks like on IE8 and IE9 none of the blur effects is working, while with IE10 even the RGBa (first version) should work fine. But it does not work on my Windows 7 System (maybe on Windows 8 it does??).
I see the filter:blur might work within IE8 and IE9 (but I can only test it out of a IE10 Version)

Did you ever have similar problems? With a complete different solution?

It has to work even without javascript, so if I use a jquery plugin I need some work around before (white textcolor which javascript sets to black first)

Answer (score 0):

use filter the filter takes three arguments for color, direction and strength. direction is taken as an angle , to approximate a 2px X and 2px Y offset, a direction of 135 degrees (135 degrees is 90 degrees plus 45 degrees) and strength of 2 is chosen

```
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=2,color=ff0000);
```

Comment: Hi

I tried different approaches - shadow does not seem to work. See my test page here: 
http://dokumente-online.com/test-blur.html

Comment: the filter:blur seems to work in IE 8 and ie9 (I can only test it from Ie10 when changing the browser-mode) - but with ie10 it does not work anylonger...

Comment: With ie10 only text-shadow seems to produce a blur effect, but it cant not work with rgba (transparent) colors. So i had to set the text color to a very light grey.

Comment: Hm, wo strange
on my system the text-blur + rgba does not seem to work within IE10
on browsershot.org it seems to work fine: see that picture http://browsershots.org/screenshots/16ca432f174fcfe5f640f6c68e78e417